# How to put a html element to json dictionary

Tags: python, html, json

In a python script,

I have the below structure. How can I  assign the try-except block to Json.dumps as key: 'html' and value:html?

Thanks...

```
sql = '''
'''

params = ()

try:
    cur.execute(sql, params) 
    result = cur.fetchall()
    if len(result) > 0:
         print '''
            <h2> Work Basket </h2>
            <table class=infoTable>
            <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          '''

          for x in result:
              print ''
              print '</table>'                                                 
except Exception, e:
     print e

print json.dumps({'html': html})
```